# Google Apps script - Read a row from Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I am trying to write some data to my Apptivo CRM system, which integrates Google Forms.

The script that writes the submitted form data to a spreadsheet and moves it into the CRM system is shown below. This script will apparently read the last spreadsheet row (the latest data) and using a CRM key will create a new CRM lead. So far, so good.

```
    function onSubmit(e)
{  
  var intIndex = e.range.getRow();
  var sheetValues = e.values;    
  var jsonString = {
    lastName : sheetValues[1],
    emailId  : sheetValues[2],
    phone : sheetValues[3],
    description: sheetValues[4],
  };

  var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(jsonString);

  var strLeadURL = 'http://www.apptivo.com/app/dao/lead?a=createLead&leadData=' + encodeURIComponent(json) + "&formKey=" + "MuFxNzDzznGjDN";  

  try
  {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(strLeadURL);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("I" + intIndex).setValue("Created in App");
  }
  catch(ex)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("I" + intIndex).setValue("Failed to create in App");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("J" + intIndex).setValue(ex);
  }  
}
```

My question: I would like to create CRM leads from another spreadsheet which gets the data from other sources, not forms. So the script triggering mechanism here can't be FormSubmit. In other words, I want to trigger the exact same script when a new line gets added to the Spreadsheet (Insert_Row), then insert that new line into the CRM as a lead.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onEdit() native container trigger in Google Sheets, if what you are doing programmatically does not require authenticated access, otherwise the process would be the same, just use a different function name and manually set a container based  (Spreadsheet) trigger for that function for the On edit event.

[image]
Here is an example that tests the edits for the last row and a minimum length of data being entered / inserted into the spreadsheet.

```
function processEdits(event){
  try{
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var rangeLength =  r.getNumColumns();
    var editRow = parseInt(r.getRow()); // get the row the edit happend on 
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var expectedLength = 12; // the minimum expected lenght of the added row

    // check if edit was last row in spreadsheet and the expected length
    if((lastRow == editRow) && (rangeLength >= expectedLength)){
      // Do some wicked processing
    } 
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that handles the input of data one cell at a time (manually) if ever you need this use case too.

It triggers only when the last row has the required length, no matter what cell we fill first. (needs of course also an onEdit trigger)

```
function processEvent(e){
  var rowValues = '';
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var rowNum =  range.getRowIndex();
  var colNum =  range.getColumnIndex();
  var minLength = 5;
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(rowNum,1,1,minLength).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var n=0;n<minLength;n++){
    if(rowData[0][n]!=''){
      rowValues+=' | '+rowData[0][n];
    }
  }
  Logger.log('rowValues ='+rowValues+'  length = '+(rowValues.split('|').length-1));
  if(rowNum == lastRow && rowValues.split('|').length > minLength){
    // processing
    Browser.msgBox('process data');
  } 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are addressing this from a single entry at a time.  If you look at my code, it is looking to ensure that the single edit event contains the expected range of data, as in from a paste or range.setValues() call.  I made that distinction from the note in the original posting "...new line gets added to the Spreadsheet (Insert_Row)..."

Comment: you're right , sorry I misread getNumColumns() , I thought getColumnIndex()...I'll edit my answer ;-)